# Give HTML time to render its text

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vbscript, hta

I have a very long VBScript code which runs in an HTA. The script includes DOM manipulation, DLL calls, and other scrips. Now I had a problem because it takes a significant amount of time to render the text on screen because there are a lot of scripts that pause the HTML parsing.

Now I'm planning to create a simple **delay** that would block the code execution but not the HTML parsing. But I don't know how to do it.

**Update**

Here is a sample code of what I want(sorry please don't mind the syntax I'm new to HTA vbs)

```
Sub Window_Onload()
    Call Main()
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim delay
    el.innerHtml = "Please"
    el2.innerHtml = "Help"
    el3.innerHtml = "me"

    'more scripts here
    'more scripts here
    'more scripts here
    'more scripts here

    el4.innerHtml = "this element is dependent to other scripts"
    el5.innerHtml = "this element is dependent to other scripts"
    el6.innerHtml = "this element is dependent to other scripts"

    delay = 2
    Call PauseAndRenderHtml(delay) 'this function will block the code execution
                                   'but not the html parsing

   'more scripts here

    Do While True
       'very long scripts that loops and pause, loops and pause........
    Loop
End Sub

Sub PauseAndRenderHtml(timeToBreath)
   'Take a breath :)
   'breath/pause for timeToBreath seconds
End Sub
```

**I need the function `PauseAndRenderHtml()`**

Comment: Can you post your HTA Code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use. For example, in a `For` loop, I'll call this at each loop and it'll update the HTML.

```
'This sleep function produces a near-instant delay for inserting a break in script execution
'mainly for updating HTML in the middle of script execution.
Sub Sleepy
    strCmd = "%COMSPEC% /c"
    objShell.Run strCmd,0,1
End Sub
```

Comment: heyy,.. thank you so much, this works for me but I wonder what this line of code does?, Can it cause any security issues?

Comment: I'm so sorry I already marked it correct but then I realize that this code did not actually delay/pause the code execution. "YES" it did render the html but sometimes the bug still occurs because there are times that the html takes more time to render than executing the comman `%COMSPEC% /c`. So after executing this command, the html is not yet rendered. Is there any way to control the amount of time to execute the command so there is more time for HTML to render its display? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a timer as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/03/30/how-can-i-temporarily-pause-a-script-in-an-hta.aspx) might help:

```html
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
     APPLICATIONNAME="Sample"
>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
  idTimer = window.setTimeout(GetRef("PausedSection"), 10000, "VBScript")

  Sub PausedSection
    ContinueWork
    window.clearTimeout(idTimer)
  End Sub

  Sub ContinueWork
    'other code here
  End Sub
</script>

<body>
...
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the idea but I think this workaround is not what I'm looking for. This would work in other situations but not for me, that is because the function that you invoke in `setTimeout()` will be called after all the stack in its function where it is called is empty. I want to call the `PausedSection()` function at the very moment where it is invoked, and block the code execution but not the HTML parsing :) is this even possible? I'm so sorry I'm new to HTA using vbs.

Comment: @Thorax Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me here. The above code calls `PausedSection` after the timeout expires, which then calls `ContinueWork` with all your other code. The HTML rendering should continue during the timeout period. AFAICS that's exactly what you've been asking for.

Answer (score 0):

On page load, execute this as the first statement of your ASP script

```
Response.Buffer = false
```

This should render the HTML until there is a call to ASP or COM DLLs.

However, since in ASP, HTML and Logic are in the same page, it is more sequential.

Note: Response.Buffer is set to true by default and server will not send output until all of the scripts on the page have been processed, or until the Flush or End method has been called

Comment: Hi sory I forgot to mention that its a HTA. But does this also implies in HTA?

Comment: I've not coded a lot on HTA files. But I guess it applies there too. Let us know how it goes

Comment: I already tried it, but it give me an error `"variable is undefined: Response"`. I guess it wont work in HTA, but thanks anyway :)